# Show Featured Image in else statement

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails

This is how i am loading the post thumbnail image ?

What if there is no image, i want to show a default image ?

How can i show that.

Here is the code i use to display thumbnail.

```
        $html .= '<div class="post event" id="post-'.$post->ID.'">

                    <a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'"> '.get_the_post_thumbnail().' </a>

                    <div class="content">
                        <span class="title">
                            <a title="'.$post->post_title.'" href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a>
                        </span>                                             
                        <div class="addl-123">';                            

                    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'sublocation');
                    if($terms)
                    {
                        $out = array();
                        foreach ($terms as $term)
                        {
                            $out[] = '<a class="' .$term->slug .'" href="' .get_term_link( $term->slug, 'sublocation') .'">' .$term->name .'</a>';
                        }
                        //echo join( ', ', $out);
                        $html .= join( ', ', $out);
                    }

                    if($is_parent != 0)
   {
    $address = get_post_meta($is_parent,'address',true);
         }
   else
   {
    $address = get_post_meta($post->ID,'address',true);
         }
         if(!$address){ $address='-'; }
   if($address && $address!="-"){$html .= "<b>".$address."</b>";}

    $html .= '<p>Timinigs: '.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cstimings', true). ' </p>';

        $html .= '</div>
```

On line no 2 of code, i am able to display thumbnail of posts who have featured images. but for other posts there are no featured images. so, for such posts i want to display default image.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

The featured image-related functions do not offer any way to define a default/fallback image. So, you'll have to define one yourself, e.g.

```
<?php $featured_image = ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail() : get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/img_not_available.png' ); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $featured_image; ?></a>
```

### Edit

Three changes:

1. More explicit conditional. `get_the_post_thumbnail()` returns an empty string rather than `false` if no image is found.
2. Updated the default image with yours. Note: use `get_template_directory_uri()` and not `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.
3. Cleaned up interspersed PHP/HTML, to help eliminate syntax errors

Note also: example code assumes a context of *inside the loop*. Modify accordingly if it is used outside the loop.

Comment: not working . its showing blank page after this

Comment: Then you have a syntax error somewhere. This is just example/proof-of-concept code, that you will need to adapt to your own needs. Also: where is your default image?

Comment: i will edit and paste the whole code. I just added the whole code. please see line no 2 in the code it is used for displaying the thumbnail.

Comment: my default image is here get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/images/img_not_available.png"

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: should i just replace the 2nd line with your code

Comment: "*should i just replace the 2nd line with your code*" - that's an exercise that is left up to the reader.

Comment: sorry, didnt understand that. I am not great at wordpress codes. could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This code works from your child themes functions file.

On top of this you can also set a default fallback in case there are no images in a post:

```
    function wpforce_featured() {
      global $post;
      $already_has_thumb = has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
          if (!$already_has_thumb)  {
          $attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );
                      if ($attached_image) {
                            foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
                            set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment_id);
                            }
                       } else {
                            set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '414');
                       }
                    }
  }  //end function
add_action('the_post', 'wpforce_featured');
add_action('save_post', 'wpforce_featured');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'wpforce_featured');
add_action('new_to_publish', 'wpforce_featured');
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'wpforce_featured');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'wpforce_featured');
```

Source http://wpforce.com/automatically-set-the-featured-image-in-wordpress/

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()):
    the_post_thumbnail();   
else: ?>
<!-- Do default stuff here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No not this one. i want something like above.